# get Response token from Observable Response in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to get Response token from `Observable Response` method in my CustomHttp.ts in angular 4.

CustomHttp.ts

```
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
        constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) 
         {
            defaultOptions.withCredentials=true;
            super(backend, defaultOptions);
        }
```

Get Method in CustomHttp.ts

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.res(super.get(appConfig.apiUrl + url, this.addJwt(options)).catch(this.handleError));
}
```

Res Method:

```
 private res(Response:any)
 {
    return Response;
 }
```

Its not working. How to get Response token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is clear, how you try to achieve it is as clear is muddy water.

use the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) :

```js
http
  .get<MyDataType>('myEndpoint', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<MyDataType>.
    // You can inspect its headers:
    console.log(resp.headers.get('Authorization'));
    // And access the body directly, which is typed as MyDataType as requested.
    console.log(resp.body);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to fetch `authorization` header in you component.If so, You can `subscribe` to `get` method and retrive the response header as below.

```
get(<your url here for your backend>)
.map(res => console.log("Authorization: " + resp.headers.get('Authorization')
```